# How to do redirect instead of response to Get method

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a `Get` method

```
[Route("login/{code}")]
public class LoginController : Controller {
  [HttpGet]
  public void Login(string code) {
    bool resp = TryToLogin(code);

    if (resp == true) {
      redirectToSiteOne;
    } else {
      redirectToSiteTwo;
    }
  }
}
```

And I don't understand how to make redirect to another site (there is must be redirect from api.example.com to example.com *maybe it's important*)

Comment: Can you not do this client-side instead, depending on the response from `login`?

Comment: @Tudor no, there is some of social network api's and they redirect client by calling my get method

Comment: What your trying to do here is wrong.. return the URL in this call and tell the social network APIs to use that value and redirect in the client.

Comment: @JoshStevens in my method I must to work with parameters, which SN take me -and after it host must show siteOne or siteTwo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 methods to do that :

Method 1 - change `void` return type to `HttpResponseMessage`

```
var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
res.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
return response;
```

Method 2 - change `void` return type to `RedirectResult`

```
return RedirectPermanent("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Response.Redirect(url)
```

At the end the **api** is simply a web page and it can redirect to another web page instead of returning values.